# Spring Boot Security "Authentication Manager" doesn't receive username parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

```
public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request){
    authManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getUsername(), 
                    request.getPassword()
            )
    );
    return null; // returns other stuff, irrelevant
}
```

The result I get in the console is:

```
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.password,u1_0.role,u1_0.username from user u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
```

If I print what is inside `authManager.authenticate(...)` I  get:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=test, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]
```

`Principal=USERNAME`, so the username is lost when `authManager.authenticate()` executes, and I don't understand the problem.
This is the service

```
package com.XX.XX.security.service;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import com.XX.XX.security.auth.AuthenticationRequest;

@Service
public class AuthenticationService {
    private final AuthenticationManager authManager;

    public AuthenticationService(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        this.authManager = authManager;
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request){
        authManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));

        return null;
    }
}
```

Also this is the only other class where AuthenticationManager is mentioned

```
package com.XX.XX.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception{
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
package com.XX.XX.security.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    public SecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter, AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.jwtAuthFilter = jwtAuthFilter;
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

I can add more information from any class if needed

[image: authentication structure]

Comment: Isn't that that the log from Hibernate shows a placeholder for a parameter instead of the actual value? Do you actually manage to log in or get some kind of error?

Comment: Seems reasonable that it does show a placeholder indeed. I get 403 forbidden when I enter the correct username and password with postman, and no JWT back (it should retrtieve the JWT made with the username and other parameters). I assumed it didn't get the username because of the placeholder, but makes sense now that you say it. Thanks, I'll try a different perspective and if the problem persist I will make anotther post.

Comment: It feels like something is missing. `AuthenticationManager` doesn't use Hibernate by default. Even if you were using `JdbcUserDetailsManager`, by default the table is named `users`, not `user`. I think what would be helpful is to know what is inside of `AuthenticationManager` and how it's configured. Maybe that's in `SecurityConfig`.

Comment: Edited to add SecurityConfig